# Parse framework in Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, linker-errors

My app that I am making requires Parse framework, but when I import Parse framework into my app, I get many errors that say the following in Apple Mach-O Linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_BFExecutor_$_Background in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFQuery.o)
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCachedCommandRunner.o)
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFRetryingCommandRunner.o)
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskQueue.o)
...
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskHTTPRequestOperation.o)
objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If you know how to fix this, and make the app able to build, please let me know.

Comment: Add the library/framework that has the classes `BFExecutor` and `BFTaskCompletionSource`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have the bolts.framework in your app